# Access tomcat that is running under firewall'd PC

Tags: firewall, tomcat

I can access my tomcat on my local system `http://localhost:8080/MyApp` but when i access it like this `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/MyApp` where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is my public ip, It doesn't seem to work.

The problem is that my system has shared internet connection and that public ip is being shared among multiple computers. And the central router configuration is not in my control.
I cant even use remote desktop or cant even ping my public ip.

My question is, is their any way i can access tomcat from remote system? 
 (*I thought if i can use team viewer on my system then why not tomcat is accessible.* )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are running behind a NAT firewall. In which case the only way you can get access inbound to your server is to gain access to the firewall or router that is doing the NATting and configure it to forward inbound requests to your server (google port forwarding or address translation to find out more)

The reason why teamviewer works i suspect is that the daemon on your server initiates an OUTBOUND connection from your server which you make use of through their software

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple computers sharing a single IP address?  You want to be able to access the site from the internet or from your internal network?  You can use a proxy to send requests to Yourcomputershostname:8080 but you need to explain a little more I think.